# Having trouble using matplotlib.colormaps

Tags: python, matplotlib

Im having trouble with using the colormaps from matplotlib. In the line where I write "cmap = mpl.colormaps[cmap_name]" the error: "AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'colormaps'" occurs (cmap == 'Blues'). I was sure I needed to use it that way, does anyone understand the problem?

I looked in up how to use the function, they do it the same way.

Comment: Maybe you have a local file called "matplotlib.py"?  Did the line `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` work without troubles?  Depending on how you want to use the colormap, you could also just write `cmap = cmap_name` or `cmap = plt.get_cmap(cmap_name)`.

Comment: I had the same error today with the code which was working fine ~6 month before. I reinstalled matplotlib but it didn't help. Have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps update to matplotlib version >= 3.5

Ref: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/25916#issuecomment-1554331806